# bundle install failed due to Bundler::GemspecError: Could not read gem at

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rvm, bundle

I'm getting these errors while installing a bundle:

```
 ✗ bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
Resolving dependencies...

Bundler::GemspecError: Could not read gem at /Users/liuxin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/cache/i18n-0.6.11.gem. It may be corrupted.
An error occurred while installing i18n (0.6.11), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install i18n -v '0.6.11'` succeeds before bundling.

✗ gem install i18n -v '0.6.11'
ERROR:  Error installing i18n:
    invalid gem: package metadata is missing in /Users/liuxin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/cache/i18n-0.6.11.gem

✗ rvm list

rvm rubies

=* ruby-1.9.3-p547 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.1.2 [ x86_64 ]
```

Comment: `rm  -f /Users/liuxin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/cache/i18n-0.6.11.gem` then try again `gem install i18n`

Comment: This is what i was looking for. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 37, accepted):

It seems that the `bundler` went to cache for the gem, so just remove the cached gem, and try again with installation of the gem:

```
$ rm -f /Users/liuxin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/cache/i18n-0.6.11.gem
$ gem install i18n
```

Comment: FYI, this solution worked for me on a different gem (warden).  I just deleted the whole cache directory; the next time I ran bundle install it succeeded.